# Error when porting libxml2 to JavaScript using Emscripten

Tags: javascript, emscripten

I am new to Emscripten and I am trying to follow the steps presented by [Alon](http://mozakai.blogspot.com/2012/03/howto-port-cc-library-to-javascript.html) and I encountered some errors when testing the compiled javascript file:

`nodejs xmllint.test.js --noout --schema test.xsd test.xml`

The error is as follows:

> /home/ray/Downloads/libxml2-2.9.2/xmllint.test.js:1
>   aughtException",(function(ex){if(!(ex instanceof ExitStatus)){throw
>   ex}}))}els
>                                                                       ^ abort(9) at Error
>       at jsStackTrace (/home/ray/Downloads/libxml2-2.9.2/xmllint.test.js:1:27407)
>       at stackTrace (/home/ray/Downloads/libxml2-2.9.2/xmllint.test.js:1:27590)
>       at abort (/home/ray/Downloads/libxml2-2.9.2/xmllint.test.js:15:29716)
>       at Array.PU (/home/ray/Downloads/libxml2-2.9.2/xmllint.test.js:8:4039)
>       at Array.gk [as 4] (/home/ray/Downloads/libxml2-2.9.2/xmllint.test.js:7:652579)
>       at Xj (/home/ray/Downloads/libxml2-2.9.2/xmllint.test.js:7:642870)
>       at Wj (/home/ray/Downloads/libxml2-2.9.2/xmllint.test.js:7:642279)
>       at pC (/home/ray/Downloads/libxml2-2.9.2/xmllint.test.js:5:817226)
>       at KB (/home/ray/Downloads/libxml2-2.9.2/xmllint.test.js:5:800787)
>       at hB (/home/ray/Downloads/libxml2-2.9.2/xmllint.test.js:5:770317) If this abort() is unexpected, build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 which can
>   give more information.

Does anyone have the same issue? Thanks!